# Copy photos taken between two time ranges

Tags: windows, powershell, sorting, photos, exif

I am a student and photograph the blackboard often.  I'm trying to sort my photos into folders, one folder for each class.

How could I copy all photos taken on Mondays and Wednesdays between 10:30 and 12:00, and add them to a certain folder?

Is there a utility for this, or should I try messing around with powershell?

Comment: You can certainly use Powershell if you'd like. Though there are existing tools outside of Powershell that have been developed for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Use [exiftool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/)'s [Filename and Directory tag based reorganization](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/filename.html) ability.

One example from there -- but feel free to research for your exact solution.
Exiftool is a powerful utility.

```
exiftool -d %Y-%m-%d "-directory<datetimeoriginal" image.jpg
```

Move 'image.jpg' into a directory with a name given by DateTimeOriginal, in the form '2006-03-27'.

You might want to use something like `%Y-%m-%d-%H` to organize by the hour and then merge your hours. Or, you might rename your files with a suffix `%Y-%m-%d-%H%M` and then sort them out for the 10:30-12:00 time window.

**Update**: Check [PhotoMove 2.5](http://www.mjbpix.com/automatically-move-photos-to-directories-or-folders-based-on-exif-date/) it is based on exiftool and referred from its homepage.

Comment: Thanks, do you know if they have a GUI version?

Comment: @wizlog, I've not used any GUI for this tool, its strength is on command line. However, the homepage does refer some in the "Related Utilities" section near the end. (http://u88.n24.queensu.ca/~bogdan/, which takes you to http://u88.n24.queensu.ca/exiftool/forum/index.php/topic,2750.0.html but there is also a note: http://u88.n24.queensu.ca/exiftool/forum/index.php/topic,4553.0.html)

Comment: Actually your objective does not need a lot of action -- just one command with the right filter in powershell should do it.

Comment: @wizlog here is another which seems made for your objective -- [PhotoMove 2.5](http://www.mjbpix.com/automatically-move-photos-to-directories-or-folders-based-on-exif-date/)